# Get element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, html-table

How do I get every td in a row of a table?

> HTML

```
<table> 
 <tr>
  <td>
  <td>Second td!</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <td>Another second td!</td>
 </tr>
```

> jQuery

```
$allrows = $("table tr");
//get all td in an index of $allrows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use this selector to get every `td` element that is inside a `tr` which in turn is inside a `table`.

  **`$("table tr td");`**
- If you want to restrict the selection to the specific hierarchy you
  have (table - tr - td), I mean in case you have more tables nested, but you just want to target the parent `td` elements. In this case you can use `>` which targets only the immediate children:

  **`$("table > tr> td");`**
- If you dont care about a specific hierearchy, let say you are using
  `tbody`, or if you want to select all the td inside a table regardless
  if you have nested tables you can use this:

  **`$("table td");`**

**EDIT:**

If you want to keep the variableyou have with the list of rows (`$allrows`) and select the `td` elements from there, you can use then the `children()` function. If you'd like, you could restrict the children selection to `td` elements only:

`$allrows.children('td').css("color", "red");`

Comment: Hello. Is there a way where I can get all the td of every index of $allrows?

Comment: is `$allrows` the id of your row elements? if yes, you can use this `$("#$allrows td")`. If you just want to select all the tds you can use just `$("td")`. Although you could probablly want to restrict the selection to a container so you dont get all the tds of the entire page, let's say `$("#myContainer td")`

Comment: $allrows is the variable where all the rows are stored. Then i would like to get all the td's in that variable..

Comment: Ah ok I got you, in that case you can use `find` to find children elements: `$allrows.find('td')`. This will get you all the tds inside each element in the $allrows list. If you want to manipulate the tds you coul use an `each` function: 
`$allrows.fint('td').each(function() {
    /* Do something here */
});`

Comment: I'm getting near on what I wanna get. Thanks for your help! But is there a way though to manipulate what index of $allrows? like $allrows[0].getallthetd? Your code is right but it still directly gets all the td.

Comment: gaaah! ok i used children() Thank you!

Comment: excellent! Glad I could help. I will update the answer to include the `children()` option.

Answer (score 2):

Try jquery `each()` like:

```
$("table tr td").each(function(){
   // Do what ever you want here
});
```

Ex:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("table tr td").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).html());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: $allrows = $("table tr"); can't I use the each() method with $allrows?

Comment: You can @MelSyGallosa

Answer (score 0):

Remove the period from before the table like so:

```
$("table tr")
```

The period states a class so the way you have it you are looking for the class `.table` row.  Removing the period will look for the element `table`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put a dot before the table tag, dots are used to select classes.

```
$("table tr");
```